# Creating blank space of equivalent size to author names for peer-reviewed paper

Tags: spacing

I am writing a conference paper that requires that the author names be omitted for the purposes of anonymous review.  Rather than just omit the author names and affiliations, I would like to include a blank space of equivalent size so the formatting of the remainder of the document remains the same.

I have found references on this and other websites to the use of \protect and \phantom, but they don't seem to work when I use them in an author block; I get an error about a "Missing } inserted".  I'm using MikTex 2.9.  Any suggestions?

Minimal working example (with extra packages included in case there are conflicts):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.0cm, right=2.0cm,
columnsep=0.8cm]{geometry}

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0.2cm}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My Paper}

\author{
   \protect\phantom{
   John Doe, Joe Blow, Jo Schmo \\
   Some Random Company, USA \\
   \texttt{jd,jb,js}\@company.com}}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to "phantom" each line separately.

```
\author{
   \phantom{John Doe, Joe Blow, Jo Schmo} \\
   \phantom{Some Random Company, USA} \\
   \phantom{\texttt{jd,jb,js}\@company.com}}
```

> [image]